# NodeJS output is function instead of printed strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, printing, arguments

I am having trouble printing the correct result in NodeJS, why isn't my code printing the strings in the correct way ? I feel like console.log is not called at all. Why do I get :

```
[Function]
[Function]
[Function]
[Function]
```

Expected result:

```
Tigrou (buddy of Spider) was here!
Spider (buddy of Tigrou) was also here!
Tigrou (buddy of Spider) are in a boat...
1 (buddy of 2)3
```

The code I thought would work:

```
function build_sentence(...args)
{
    var i = 0
    var s = ""
    for (let arg of args)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            i++
            s += "(buddy of " + arg + ") "
        }
        else
        {
            s += arg + " "
            i++
        }
    }
    return s
}

function mycurry(build_sentence)
{
    return function(...args)
    {
        if (!args)
        {
            return build_sentence();
        }
        else
        {
            return mycurry(build_sentence.bind(this, ...args))
        }
    }
}

const curried = mycurry(build_sentence);
console.log(curried("Tigrou")("Spider")(" was here!"))
console.log(curried("Spider")("Tigrou")(" was also here!"))
console.log(curried("Tigrou", "Spider", " are in a boat... "))
console.log(curried(1)(2, 3))
```

Comment: You are passing a function (understood by the output you presented), so you have to invoke the function to actually get the value you want from it.

Comment: Yes I invoked the function on the last 5 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full working solution for you (except the string spacing)

```js
const build_sentence_n_params = 3;

function build_sentence(...args)
{
    var i = 0
    var s = ""
    for (let arg of args)
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            i++
            s += "(buddy of " + arg + ") "
        }
        else
        {
            s += arg + " "
            i++
        }
    }
    return s
}

// A generic n-parameter curry helper, that returns fn return value
// after n-parameters given, and continues currying with more parameters.
// Note that in this configuration, the caller would also need
// to know how many parameters to give before a value is returned.
function ncurry(fn, n)
{
    // Note that we have to return an outer function here, rather than just
    // returning `curry` function directly, so `params` is unique for each
    // initial call to `curried`.
    return function(...args) {    
        // Initial arguments (note: we can use this array without copy, since
        // rest params will always be a new array)
        const params = args;
        // This function contains the return logic without having to duplicate it below
        function next() {
            // If we have all params, call the given function, otherwise
            // return the curry function again for more parameters
          return !n || params.length >= n ? fn.call(null, ...params) : curry;
        }
        // The outer function is only called once, but this curry
        // function will be called for each additional time.
        function curry(...args) {
            // Accumulate additional arguments
            params.push(...args)
            return next();
        };
        return next();
    };
}

function mycurry(build_sentence)
{
    // Call the generic n-parameter curry helper to generate
    // a specific curry function for our purposes.
    return ncurry(build_sentence, build_sentence_n_params);
}

const curried = mycurry(build_sentence);
console.log(curried("Tigrou")("Spider")(" was here!"))
console.log(curried("Spider")("Tigrou")(" was also here!"))
console.log(curried("Tigrou", "Spider", " are in a boat... "))
console.log(curried(1)(2, 3))
```

Comment: You have to have some way of differentiating each call from the final call. You could use what you had above, where it was looking for a final call with no parameters (except for your error of using `!args` rather than `!args.length`), but of course that would require you to add to the console.log line another final invocation with no arguments (i.e.`()`), which you said you weren't allowed to do in this case. You could look for a specific type or even punctuation (e.g. periods, exclamation marks) at the end of each argument, and if it exists then it ends the curry and returns the final value.

Answer (score 0):

Your method invocations are quite confusing so I took the liberty to simplify your code.

If you run the following:

```
 const curried = build_sentence("Tigrou", "Spider", " was here!");
 console.log(curried);
```

You will get your desired output:

> Tigrou (buddy of Spider)  was here!

Why you are using the mycurry method is beyond my understanding.

When debugging your code, the sentence is already built on the first invocation, and what happens is that the subsequent invocations are not really invocations of the inner functions.

Comment: Actually I was using it to write a function that curryfies another function. Therefore I would just like to modify the two functions and not modify how I am calling them. Where is the mycurry method behaving bad ?

Answer (score 0):

the main issue about our code is that `!args` is all the time false, as `[]` to boolean is also `true`.

you have to use `!args.length`. however you should add an extra call to your curried function usage like `curried(1)(2, 3)()`.

the other approach is using comparison of curried function number of required params (`build_sentence.length`) and the number of params passed (`args.length`), but it's not working with spread scenario.

upd:

ex.1 - using `Function.prototype.length` property

```js
const curry = fn => 
  (...args) => 
    fn.length <= args.length 
      ? fn(...args) 
      : curry(fn.bind(this, ...args));

const func1 = (a, b, c) => `${a},${b},${c}`;
const func2 = (...args) => args.join(',');

console.log(curry(func1)(1,3)(4));
console.log(curry(func1)(1,3,4));
console.log(curry(func1)(1)(3)(4));

console.log(curry(func2)(1));
```

in this case currying will work fine for `func1` (function that has enumerable number of arguments) because `func1.length` = 3. however for `func2` - `func2.length` = 0, so `(curry(func1))` will be executed after first call.

ex.2 - using number of arguments passed

```js
const curry = fn => 
  (...args) => 
    !args.length 
      ? fn() 
      : curry(fn.bind(this, ...args));
      
const func = (...args) => args.join(',');

console.log(curry(func)(1)(2,3,4)(5)());
```

in this case function currying will only return result of `fn` executing, when called with no arguments. however it will handle innumerable arguments of curried function properly.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler solution? Could you provide me a working example ? I have trouble understanding what you explained, particularly "spread scenario"